# iterate over stdin fish (context: filter music files by genre grep)

Tags: fish

I have this:

```
for file in **/*.ogg;  
    if ffprobe "$file" 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/^ *GENRE *: (.*)/\1/p' | grep -q "$argv"; 
        echo "$file"
    else
    end
end
```

but I would like to turn it into a function which will take a list of filenames as standard-input:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -exec du -h {} + | cut -f2 | filterByGenre Classical
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
function filterByGenre
    while read line
        do stuff with $line
    end
end
```

or

```
function filterByGenre
    set listOfLines (cat)
    for line in $listOfLines
        do stuff with $line
    end
end
```